# Polymer: dom-repeat like local variable for elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, dom-repeat

I'd like to create a control that converts the data into something I need.

At the moment, I solve this with a global variable. The code looks something like this:
(The lowercase functionality is only to demonstrate it in a simple way. Usually I want to use it for arrays of objects. e.g. to get distinct values of certain names and ids)

```
<dom-module id="my-tolower">
  <script>
    "use strict";
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-tolower',
      properties: {
        input: {
          type: String,
          value: "",
        },
        output:{
          type: String,
          value: "",
          notify: true,
        }
      },
      observers:[
        "_inputChanged(input)",
      ],
      _inputChanged: function(newInput, oldInput){
        this.set("output", newInput.toLowerCase());
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Usage:

```
<my-tolower input="[[output.name]]" output="{{lower}}">[[lower]]</my-tolower>
```

This solution works great if I am only using the variable `lower` only once. Inside of a `<dom-repeat>`, I get a problem.

How can I easily make a custom variable that is only available inside of `my-tolower`? Exactly the same way as Polymer's `dom-repeat` does?

I took a look at the code at [Polymer's `<dom-repeat>` sources](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html), but I have no idea how that works. Is this even possible in a custom element? Do I need to create a custom template?

---

To explain my problem better I have added a bigger Example that explains my problem in detail.

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',
    ready: function(){
      //In my real Problem this value comes from a websocket...
      this.devices = [{
        name: "PC 1",
        components: [
          {
            name: "HDD1",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor1",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor1", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor2", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Another Piece Of Hardware",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor4",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor3", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor4", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "PC 2",
        components: [
          {
            name: "My third piece of hardware",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor1",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor2", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor3", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }];
      //this.devices must not be changed!
    }
  });
  
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-distinct',
    properties: {
      inputs: {
        type: String
      },
      outputs:{
        computed: '_getDistincts(inputs, path)',
        notify: true
      },
      path: {
        type: String,
        value: ""
      }
    },
    _getDistincts(inputs, path){
      let result = [];
      
      for(let key in inputs){
        if(inputs.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          let x = inputs[key];
          if(path && path != ""){
            x = x[path];
          }
          
          if(result.indexOf(x) < 0){
            result.push(x);
          }
          else{
            //Already Exists
          }
        }
      }
      
      return result;
    }
    
  });
  
 
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  As you can see, there is always "Processor1", "Processor2" and "Pocessor3" available although this is only the result of the last computers component. You can see the right result (but with duplicates) if you use the comment I made instead.
  
  <dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
      <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[devices]]" as="device">
          <li>[[device.name]]
          <ul>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[device.components]]" as="component">
              <li>[[component.name]]
                <ul>
                  <!-- This is my code with using distinct -->
                  <my-distinct inputs="[[component.processors]]" 
                      outputs="{{distinctProcessorNames}}" 
                      path="type">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[distinctProcessorNames]]" as="processorName">
                      <li>[[processorName]]
                        <!-- Here I could iterate over all processors (filtered) and list their usages-->
                      </li>
                    </template>
                  </my-distinct>
                  
                  <!-- This is my code without using distinct. -->
                  <!--template is="dom-repeat" items="[[component.processors]]" as="processor">
                    <li>[[processor.type]]
                      <ul>
                        <li>Used for [[processor.usage]]</li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </template-->
                </ul>
              </li>
            </template>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </template>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpYJjG)

Comment: can't you add it in the `properties` declaration list?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adding it in the `properties` declaration list. My output is already there. The problem is when you try to use `output` in an dom-repeat you will only see the last set value of output on each text.

Comment: Of course I can add an `observer` to the properties. But then I always have to add a new binding every time I want to do that. And for multiple entries my code gets really messy. That's why i prefer an element more than a behavior.

Comment: I thought you could declare the `lower` variable in the `properties` object. I may not understand what you want, maybe you could post the code that doesn't work as expected (with dom-repeat).

Comment: @Supersharp I have added a code snippet that explains my problem in a more detailled way. I want to use the distinct element multiple times in my application. This is the reason why I want to use it as a control.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, properties declared inside a `<dom-repeat>` (i.e., `lower` in this case) are **not** scoped exclusively to the `<dom-repeat>` or its iterations. Thus, each iteration is overwriting the previous `lower` value, and `lower` remains available outside the `<dom-repeat>`.

However, you could achieve a similar scoping effect by attaching an output property to each `item` iterator in the `<dom-repeat>` if `item` is an `Object`.

For example, consider an `<x-foo>` element that takes an input array of `Object`s and passes each input to `<my-tolower>`, which writes a new value into `_output` (an attached property on the iterator):

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[inputs]]" as="x">
  <!-- Attach output to a new property on item (i.e., "_output") -->
  <my-tolower input="[[x.input]]" output="{{x._output}}"></my-tolower>
</template>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      inputs: Array
    },

    _toObjArray: function(inputs) {
      // Map inputs into objects so that we can attach properties to each iterator in a dom-repeat
      return inputs.map(input => ({input}));
    }
  });

  Polymer({
    is: 'my-tolower',
    properties: {
      input: {
        type: String,
        value: "",
      },
      output: {
        computed: '_computeOutput(input)',
        notify: true,
      }
    },
    _computeOutput: function(input) {
      return input.toLowerCase();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo inputs='["aLPha", "brAVo", "CHarLiE", "DelTA", "epSiLoN"]'></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_toObjArray(inputs)]]">
        <!-- Attach output to a new property on item (i.e., "_output") -->
        <my-tolower input="[[item.input]]" output="{{item._output}}"></my-tolower>

        <div>
          <span>[[item.input]] -> [[item._output]]</span>
        </div>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vxWQQy?editors=1010)

In your code, you have a nested object, used in nested `dom-repeat`s. The same technique from above can be applied at each nesting level, but your example only needs it at the innermost level. You could give `<my-distinct>.outputs` its own "local" variable by attaching the output to the iterator (i.e., `component`):

```
<my-distinct outputs="{{component.distinctProcessorNames}}" ...>
```

Then, you'd use that in your inner `dom-repeat` like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[component.distinctProcessorNames]]" ...>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',
    ready: function(){
      this.devices = [{
        name: "PC 1",
        components: [
          {
            name: "HDD1",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor1",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor1", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor2", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Another Piece Of Hardware",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor4",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor3", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor4", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "PC 2",
        components: [
          {
            name: "My third piece of hardware",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor1",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor2", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor3", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }];
    }
  });
  
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-distinct',
    properties: {
      inputs: {
        type: String
      },
      outputs:{
        computed: '_getDistincts(inputs, path)',
        notify: true
      },
      path: {
        type: String,
        value: ""
      }
    },
    _getDistincts(inputs, path){
      let result = [];
      
      for(let key in inputs){
        if(inputs.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          let x = inputs[key];
          if(path && path != ""){
            x = x[path];
          }
          
          if(result.indexOf(x) < 0){
            result.push(x);
          }
          else {
            //Already Exists
          }
        }
      }
      
      return result;
    }
    
  });
  
 
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  
  <dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
      <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[devices]]" as="device">
          <li>[[device.name]]
            <ul>
              <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[device.components]]" as="component">
                <li>[[component.name]]
                  <ul>
                    <my-distinct inputs="[[component.processors]]" outputs="{{component.distinctProcessorNames}}" path="type">
                    </my-distinct>

                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[component.distinctProcessorNames]]" as="processorName">
                      <li>[[processorName]]</li>
                    </template>                  
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </template>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </template>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[your demo with updates](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QpxKNd?editors=1010)

You commented that you don't want to clone any objects or modify the input. That's unfortunately not possible with the iterator-property technique described above. The better option in that case is to provide a template for `<my-distinct>`, which would encapsulate any transformations without affecting the input.

Comment: Is there even a possibility to create an element without modifying the input data? Otherwise elements which require a string array will not work anymore.

Comment: @CHF IMO, the computed property (as demonstrated in the answer) provides one solution for you, in which the original input is not modified and is a string array. The computed property creates an intermediate object that allows you to attach "temporary" properties to each iterator. Another solution that is even more "temporary" is to use computed bindings instead so that the intermediate object is not available outside the `dom-repeat` (and this is a simple change to the answer). I'll update the answer later today (on the run at the moment).

Comment: with your Example code I have a problem with deeper structures. `x-foo` works only in your example. When I want to reuse `x-foo` in nested dom-repeats I think I have to use a binding again. Isn't there a way to do something like `<content input="[[_input]]"></content>` inside of `x-foo`? Am I maybe thinking too complicated?

Comment: Is there also a possibility to get this result with my currently added example? I don't want to clone the whole structure. And I even don't want to modify one of the objects themselves. Because this would destroy some others code. @tony19

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 different Polymer custom elements `<my-app>` and `<my-distinct>`.
Therefore you should declare the second one with its proper `<dom-module>` statement:

```
<dom-module id="my-distinct">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[outputs]]" as="processorName">
            <li>[[processorName]]
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Then use your computed property (based on the attribute value) `outputs` as the `items` value of `<template is="dom-repeat">`.

Demo below:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',
    ready: function(){
      //In my real Problem this value comes from a websocket...
      this.devices = [{
        name: "PC 1",
        components: [
          {
            name: "HDD1",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor1",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor1", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor2", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Another Piece Of Hardware",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor4",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor3", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor4", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "PC 2",
        components: [
          {
            name: "My third piece of hardware",
            processors: [
              {
                type: "Processor1",
                usage: "Dont Know 1"
              },
              { type: "Processor2", usage: "DontKnow2"},
              { type: "Processor3", usage: "DontKnow3"}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }];
      //this.devices must not be changed!
    }
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-distinct',
    properties: {
      inputs: {
        type: String
      },
      outputs:{
        computed: '_getDistincts(inputs, path)', notify: true
      },
      path: {
        type: String,
        value: ""
      }
    },
    _getDistincts(inputs, path){
      let result = [];
      
      for(let key in inputs){
        if(inputs.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          let x = inputs[key];
          if(path && path != ""){
            x = x[path];
          }
          
          if(result.indexOf(x) < 0){
            result.push(x);
          }
        }
      }
      //console.log( result )
      return result;
    } 
  });  
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  
  <dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
      <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[devices]]" as="device">
          <li>[[device.name]]
          <ul>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[device.components]]" as="component">
              <li>[[component.name]]
                <ul>
                  <my-distinct inputs="[[component.processors]]" path="type">
                  </my-distinct>
                
                </ul>
              </li>
            </template>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </template>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-distinct">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[outputs]]" as="processorName">
            <li>[[processorName]]
        </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```